# Use docker-compose to replicate a single service from a stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm a bit confused as I'm used to use docker-compose in a single-server environment. Now I have the idea to use a Docker Swarm cluster with docker-compose (as it's what I know better) but I'm a bit confused on how to make it work against my app's needs. For instance:

My app is made up by a `manager` app and multiple `workers`. My idea is to have the `manager` app run in the Docker Swarm manager's server (is that possible?) and then use docker-compose to **replicate the workers only** through the rest of the Swarm cluster nodes.

A small map would be something like:

```
Server A -> manager
Server B -> worker1, worker2, worker3
Server C -> worker4, worker5
```

The workers connect to the manager through a defined IP & port in the `environment` section in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

My question is: How do I start up the `manager` **only** on a single server, and how do I replicate the `worker`s **only** in the other nodes, without having a `manager` per cluster node? (as I don't want/need that). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can to define by `constraints`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  manager:
    hostname: 'manager'
    image: traefik
    deploy:
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  service:
    image: service
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 5
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
```